# Server backend to keep 2 seperate users HTML Canvas in sync in a web game

Tags: canvas, signalr, game-engine

Hi I'm making a game (a space shooter)where I am thinking of using .Net's Signal R to keep users HTML Canvas in sync between 2 separate users.

So I want a user A with the canvas in his browser to be in sync (all the game objects the same) with user B's canvas.

Do you think this is a good tech to use? If so can you give me some advices on the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

See ShootR (http://shootr.signalr.net/), built with SignalR. A space Shooter =).

https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/ShootR